# Swift Firebase project, how to read only title of a node

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app that contains clients for the user which can be added within a table view. I want to access the Firebase database of clients so i can display each client as a separate cell on my table view.
[screen cap of firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vIin.png)

so for this example I want to take out names "Tyler Huan" and "Johnny Sherman" to append them to an array, putting them into my table view. If I try to withdraw the clients property programmatically with:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)


        if let clients = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let clients2 = clients["Clients"] as? [String]{
                print(clients)
                print("this \(clients2)")
            }
        }
    }
```

It can't take out just the names because under those names are also client properties.

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: While there's an accepted answer, the structure you are using is going to cause trouble. As it is, a persons name is the node key. Suppose that person is "Cindy Lu" so that's the *key* to her node. You reference that node in 25 different places in your app for queries and such. Once day, Cindy get's married and her name is now "Cindy Smith". You would have to first, delete her node and re-write it with the updated name and the find every place that node is referenced in your structure, and re-write it! With NoSQL, common practice is to disassociate node names (keys) from the data they contain.

Comment: Additionally, what if there are special characters in the name O'Reilly or Williams Jr.? Parsing? The solution is to create node nodes with .childByAutoId. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561806/firebase-storing-data-best-practices/35562091#35562091) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845545/displaying-firebase-child-from-user-uid-to-username-in-swift-3/41883558#41883558) for some more reading. As a side note, please don't use links or images in questions. If the link changes we would have no idea what your structure looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the clients list, then use the reference to just the list of clients rather than the reference to all the information under the user. In this case, it would be `ref.child("users/(userID!)/Clients")`. Keep in mind it's a good idea to build your data structure so that you're only downloading the information you need at any given time. When you call `observeSingleEvent`, all the data under that reference will be downloaded regardless of whether you need it. Given your current data structure, this is how you could get the names:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("users/(userID!)/Clients").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        print(child.key)
    }
}
```

You can see examples in the [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).
But then again, if there are times you need the client names and not their companies, you may want to try a different structure using denormalization. For example:

```
users: {
    uid1: {
        clientNames: {
            Johnny Sherman: true,
            Tyler Huan: true,
            //...
        }
        clientProfiles: {
            Johnny Sherman: {
                Company: "Apple",
                Phone: 8675309,
                Address: "Funkytown",
                //...
            }
            Tyler Huan: {
                Company: "Microsoft",
                Phone: 0118999881999199725...3,
                Address: "Sesame Street",  
            },
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

The above structure assumes you will one day need more data for each client. It enables you to query just the names rather than whole profiles when needed. However, if you're only ever going to need their company name and won't have profiles, you can just put it as the value with their name as the key:

```
users: {
    uid1: {
        Clients: {
            Johnny Sherman: "Apple",
            Tyler Huan: "Microsoft",
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Just a couple suggestions so it's easier to query data moving forward!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much Jen. I've decided to use your second option so I can add more properties if necessary. When trying to access it it gives me this - Value of type 'Any' has no member 'key'.

Comment: Hmm, haven't used RTDB in a while, but I used to use `for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]` which might still work. If it does, I may have to ask them to update the docs since I pulled `snapshot.children` from there.

Comment: `for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]` works perfectly, it let me pull the names with `child.key` after.